# Getting Exception "Method Not Allowed" after making SOAP request using SoapCall function in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soapui

Actually am able to successfully execute this request and getting the response (as expected) using SOAPUI tool but not able to achieve this using PHP. As am not familiar with SOAP web-services, any help / guidance will be appreciated. Here is the details of Web Service and my PHP code.

WSDL = https://XYZ.DOMAIN.COM/sdc/schema/alu/wsdl/binding/soap_http/PerformanceManagementRetrievalExtnsSOAP.wsdl

Request Envelop (Header and Body)

```
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tmf:header tmf854Version="?" extAuthor="?" extVersion="?">
         <tmf:msgName>GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsRequest</tmf:msgName>
         <tmf:msgType>REQUEST</tmf:msgType>
         <tmf:communicationPattern>SimpleResponse</tmf:communicationPattern>
         <tmf:communicationStyle>RCP</tmf:communicationStyle>
      </tmf:header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsRequest>
         <sdc:pmInputList>
            <sdc:pmObjectSelect>
               <tmf:mdNm>AMS</tmf:mdNm>
               <tmf:meNm>olt0.test02</tmf:meNm>
               <tmf:propNm>/Type=Optical Measurements/R1.S1.LT3.PON16.ONT2</tmf:propNm>
            </sdc:pmObjectSelect>
            <sdc:pmParameterList>
               <sdc:pmParameter>
                  <sdc:pmParameterName>gponOntAniOpInfoTxOpticalSignalLevel</sdc:pmParameterName>
                  <sdc:pmParemeterMaxIntervals>1</sdc:pmParemeterMaxIntervals>
               </sdc:pmParameter>
            </sdc:pmParameterList>
         </sdc:pmInputList>
      </sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Response Envelope (Header and Body)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tmf:header extAuthor="?" extVersion="?" tmf854Version="?" xmlns:tmf="tmf854.v1">
         <tmf:msgName>GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsResponse</tmf:msgName>
         <tmf:msgType>RESPONSE</tmf:msgType>
         <tmf:communicationPattern>SimpleResponse</tmf:communicationPattern>
         <tmf:communicationStyle>RCP</tmf:communicationStyle>
         <tmf:activityStatus>SUCCESS</tmf:activityStatus>
         <tmf:timestamp>20200828T064424.633+0100</tmf:timestamp>
      </tmf:header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsResponse xmlns:sdc="sdcNbi" xmlns:tmf="tmf854.v1">
         <sdc:pmDataListForObject>
            <sdc:pmObjectSelect>
               <tmf:mdNm>AMS</tmf:mdNm>
               <tmf:meNm>olt0.test02</tmf:meNm>
               <tmf:propNm>/Type=Optical Measurements/R1.S1.LT3.PON16.ONT2</tmf:propNm>
            </sdc:pmObjectSelect>
            <sdc:pmDataList>
               <sdc:pmData>
                  <sdc:pmParameterName>gponOntAniOpInfoTxOpticalSignalLevel</sdc:pmParameterName>
                  <sdc:pmParameterValue>1075</sdc:pmParameterValue>
                  <sdc:pmParameterStatus>PMIS_Valid</sdc:pmParameterStatus>
               </sdc:pmData>
            </sdc:pmDataList>
         </sdc:pmDataListForObject>
      </sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

I have coded in PHP as, 

<?php

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

$username = 'XXXX';
$password = 'XXXX';
$name_space = 'AMS';
$wsdl_url = 'https://XYZ.DOMAIN.COM/sdc/schema/alu/wsdl/binding/soap_http/PerformanceManagementRetrievalExtnsSOAP.wsdl?WSDL';

try {

    $options = array(
        'location' => $wsdl_url,
        'cache_wsdl' => 0,
        'trace' => 1,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        ))
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, $options);

    // Build an object with parameters
    $auth = new stdClass();
    $auth->username = $username;
    $auth->password = $password;

    $authvalues = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
    $header =  new SoapHeader(
        $name_space,
        "Authentication",
        $authvalues,
        false
    );

    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

    $xml = '<sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsRequest>
    <sdc:pmInputList>
       <sdc:pmObjectSelect>
          <tmf:mdNm>AMS</tmf:mdNm>
          <tmf:meNm>olt0.test02</tmf:meNm>
          <tmf:propNm>/Type=Optical Measurements/R1.S1.LT3.PON16.ONT2</tmf:propNm>
       </sdc:pmObjectSelect>
       <sdc:pmParameterList>
          <sdc:pmParameter>
             <sdc:pmParameterName>gponOntAniOpInfoTxOpticalSignalLevel</sdc:pmParameterName>
             <sdc:pmParemeterMaxIntervals>1</sdc:pmParemeterMaxIntervals>
          </sdc:pmParameter>
       </sdc:pmParameterList>
    </sdc:pmInputList>
 </sdc:GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsRequest>';

    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));
    
    $response = $client->__soapCall('getPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjects', $args);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

Response 

Method Not Allowed (Exception)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using the PHP CURL library, here is the complete script

```
    <?php
    
    require_once('nokia_ams_plugin_configuration.php');
    require_once('nokia_validate_xml.php');
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    // fetching Nokia AMS plugin sdc service urls & credentials
    $ams_configuration_instance = new NokiaAMSPluginConfiguration();
    $ams_configuration = $ams_configuration_instance->get();
    
    $sdc_server_host = $ams_configuration['sdc_server_host'];
    $sdc_service_url = $ams_configuration['sdc_service_url'];
    $sdc_service_name = $ams_configuration['sdc_service_name'];
    $sdc_server_user = $ams_configuration['sdc_server_user'];
    $sdc_server_password = $ams_configuration['sdc_server_password'];
    
    $param_value = 0;
    
    // olt name, olt ip address or host, ont and stats param
    if ((!isset($argv[1])) || (!isset($argv[2])) || (!isset($argv[3])) || (!isset($argv[4])) || (!isset($argv[5]))) {
        $olt_name = 'XXX';
        $olt_host = 'XXX';
        $ont = 'XXX';
        $stats_type = 'XXX';
        $stats_param = 'XXX';
    
        // extract ont name
        $ont = extract_ont($ont, $stats_type);
    
        // echo $param_value;
        // return;
    } else {
        $olt_name = $argv[1];
        $olt_host = $argv[2];
        $ont = $argv[3];
        $stats_type = $argv[4];
        $stats_param = $argv[5];
    
        // extract ont name
        $ont = extract_ont($ont, $stats_type);
    }
    
    $host = $sdc_server_host;
    $sdc_service_url  = 'https://' . $host . '/' . $sdc_service_url;
    $sdc_service_name = 'https://' . $host . '/' . $sdc_service_name;
    $credentials = $sdc_server_user . ':' . $sdc_server_password;
    
    $request_payload = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sdc="sdcNbi" xmlns:tmf="tmf854.v1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
       <tmf:header tmf854Version="?" extAuthor="?" extVersion="?">
          <tmf:msgName>XXX</tmf:msgName>
          <tmf:msgType>XXX</tmf:msgType>
          <tmf:communicationPattern>XXX</tmf:communicationPattern>
          <tmf:communicationStyle>XXX</tmf:communicationStyle>
       </tmf:header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
          <sdc:XXX>
             <sdc:pmInputList>
                <sdc:pmObjectSelect>
                   <tmf:mdNm>' . $olt_name . '</tmf:mdNm>
                   <tmf:meNm>' . $olt_host . '</tmf:meNm>
                   <tmf:propNm>' . $stats_type . $ont . '</tmf:propNm>
                </sdc:pmObjectSelect>
                <sdc:pmParameterList>
                                <sdc:pmParameter>
                                     <sdc:pmParameterName>' . $stats_param . '</sdc:pmParameterName>
                   </sdc:pmParameter>
                </sdc:pmParameterList>
             </sdc:pmInputList>
          </sdc:XXX>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>';
    
    try {
        //setting the curl parameters
        $ch = curl_init($sdc_service_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sdc_service_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
            'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
        if ($responseCode != 200) {
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $param_value;
            return;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    
        // preparing result
        $validateXML = new NokiaValidateXml(NULL, NULL);
        // cleaning extra string from xml to validate the xml in next steps
        $cleaned_xml_string = $validateXML->cleanXMLStringCustom($response, ['soapenv:', 'tmf854:', 'sdc:'], NULL);
    
        if ($cleaned_xml_string != 'exception') {
            $xml_object = simplexml_load_string($cleaned_xml_string, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $json = json_encode($xml_object);
            $json_array = json_decode($json, true);
    
            if (!isset($json_array['Body']) || (isset($json_array['Body']['Fault']))) {
                echo $param_value;
                return;
            }
            $param_status = $json_array['Body']['GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsResponse']['pmDataListForObject']['pmDataList']['pmData']['pmParameterStatus'];
            if ($param_status == 'PMIS_Valid') {
                $param_value = $json_array['Body']['GetPerformanceMonitoringDataForObjectsResponse']['pmDataListForObject']['pmDataList']['pmData']['pmParameterValue'];
                if ($stats_type == '/type=UNI') {
                    if ($param_value == 'Instance Unavailable') {
                        $param_value = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo trim($param_value);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $param_value;
        return;
    }
    
    function extract_ont($ont, $stats_type)
    {        
        $new_ont = NULL;
    
        $pattern_rack = '/^rack=([0-9]+)$/';
        $pattern_shelf = '/^shelf=([0-9]+)$/';
        $pattern_slot = '/^slot=LT([0-9]+)$/';
        $pattern_port = '/^port=([0-9]+)$/';
        $pattern_remote_unit = '/^remote_unit=([0-9]+)$/';
    
        $ont_split = explode('/', $ont);
    
        foreach ($ont_split as $item) {
            // Rack
            if (preg_match($pattern_rack, $item)) {
                $rack_split = explode('=', $item);
                $rack_number = $rack_split[1];
                $new_ont = '/R' . $rack_number . '.';
            }
    
            // Shelf
            if (preg_match($pattern_shelf, $item)) {
                $shelf_split = explode('=', $item);
                $shelf_number = $shelf_split[1];
                $new_ont .= 'S' . $shelf_number . '.';
            }
    
            // Slot
            if (preg_match($pattern_slot, $item)) {
                $slot_split = explode('=', $item);
                $slot_number = $slot_split[1];
                $new_ont .= $slot_number . '.';
            }
    
            // Port
            if (preg_match($pattern_port, $item)) {
                $port_split = explode('=', $item);
                $port_number = $port_split[1];
                $new_ont .= 'PON' . $port_number . '.';
            }
    
            // Remote Unit
            if (preg_match($pattern_remote_unit, $item)) {
                $remote_unit_split = explode('=', $item);
                $ont_number = $remote_unit_split[1];
                $new_ont .= 'ONT' . $ont_number;
            }
        }
    
        if ($stats_type == '/type=UNI') {
            // for bandwidth stats
            $new_ont .= '.C14.P1';
        }
        return $new_ont;
    }
    ?>
```